# SSIS Pre-Execute phase in DataFlow Task

Tags: oracle, ssis, oledb, dataflowtask

I have an SSIS package with one DF task. Oledb source is oracle and Oledb destination is SqlServer, no transformations in between.The query used to pull data from source is

```
Select a.col1,a.col2,c.col1,c.col2 from table a join table b on a.id = b.id join table c on b.iid = c.iid
```

It takes .45 secs to execute in Oracle/Sql developer. When I use the same query  in the DF task the pre-execute phase dosent move further than 50%.

Things I have tried after going through various blogs and articles

```
1) Set delay validation = ture
2)Validate External metadata = false
3)One of the source column is a clob, hence set BlobTemstoragepath to a 
different drive, also the buffer temp storage path
4) increased the default buffer size and default buffer max rows
5) Set 64 bit execution to false(Just wanted to give this a try as well)
```

I am literally out of options and ideas of why it would not work. The DF task keeps spinning at Preexecute 50% for hours together.

Can someone please shed some light?

Comment: Do you have the client installed and the TSNAMES file set and all that good Oracle hoopla?

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you mean, but I do, without that my SSIS wont connect to the oracle db isnt it?

Comment: Does it connect? Have you tried any other queries? Maybe try another database? Narrow down the problem to your user, connection, database, table, etc.

Comment: I was able to narrow it down, the problem is the column with CLOB data type. Any idea what data provider i can use to extract clob data efficiently?

Comment: I'm not that good with Oracle. Can you make a view in Oracle and cast the CLOB as a different type?

Comment: @JacobH: That is posssible, but the max length for the column with clob datatype is 33974, if we convert it to another datatype we need to truncate it, and requirement dosent allow me to do that. Any other idea?Thanks for your time

Comment: Try casting as VARCHAR(MAX)  in SSIS perhaps? Using an Execute SQL task.